# I try to create a superuser but the error is no such table: users_user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

the error is :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: users_user
```

this is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
pass
```

the settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Comment: Have you `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: have you run `migrate` and `makemigration` commands?

Comment: yes i did the migrations

Answer (score 1):

Delete all migrations then... apply below commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations yourapp_name
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete all migrations file and then add below code and then do migrations

try this:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin   
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
             pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the migration folders of your apps and then type the following to reset all admin, auth, contenttypes, and sessions from the migration history and drop the tables:

```
python manage.py migrate admin zero
python manage.py migrate auth zero
python manage.py migrate contenttypes zero
python manage.py migrate sessions zero
```

Then, just do `makemigrations users` and `migrate users`.